# How to write this accumulator query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match (s:Product {type:'Phone'})-[r]->(o:Attributes) where exists(o.color) return s.name, o.color
```

This query returns each individual product name and its 'color' attribute. In this case, many duplicate products and colors will be displayed again and again. Instead, i want to return all 'colors' without duplications. For example, in the result set, there may be 100 products, but there are only 5 different colors. I want to only return the 5 different colors.

How to achieve that? Is that still possible to return s.name and the unique colors together? If not, simply returning the unique colors are fine.

EDIT:
This seems working:

```
return collect(distinct(o.color)) limit 5
```

It returns the unique 'color', but the 'limit 5' doesn't work. It returns all unique colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause limits the number of *returned records*. Your second query is returning a single record (consisting of a single collection of all the distinct colors). The `LIMIT` clause has no effect on the number of items inside that collection.

To get at most 5 unique colors related to "Phone" `Product`(s), you can do this:

```
MATCH (:Product {type:'Phone'})-->(o:Attributes)
WHERE EXISTS(o.color)
RETURN DISTINCT o.color AS color
LIMIT 5;
```

This query will return one record per unique color. To get *all* the unique colors related to "Phone" `Product`(s), just remove the `LIMIT` clause.

If you want to get a single collection of at most 5 unique colors, you can do this:

```
MATCH (:Product {type:'Phone'})-->(o:Attributes)
WHERE EXISTS(o.color)
WITH DISTINCT o.color AS color
LIMIT 5
RETURN COLLECT(color) AS colors;
```

[UPDATE]

To get the top 5 colors, in descending order of frequency:

```
MATCH (:Product {type:'Phone'})-->(o:Attributes)
WHERE EXISTS(o.color)
WITH o.color AS color, COUNT(*) AS colorCount
ORDER BY colorCount DESC
RETURN color
LIMIT 5;
```

Notice that `DISTINCT` is not needed, since the `WITH` clause uses an [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (`COUNT`) with `color` as the grouping key. This causes the output of the `WITH` clause to be records with distinct `color` values.

Comment: That's good. In addition, how to get the top 5 colors ranked by their frequencies?

Comment: if my 'color' is a variable, is there a way to make the above query work?

Comment: The last 2 queries *are* using `color` as a variable. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I mean my $color will be passed as a method parameter, and then it will be used as part of the query above.

Comment: How would you want to use such a parameter? Also, this sounds like a new question. Please create a new question, and provide full information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I will file another question.